# Preload com Cookie ou Session

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Olá pessoal tudo bem? estou utilizando um código preload esta funcionando muito bem, porem o problema é que toda vez que acessa o site carrega o preload isso incomoda muito.. gostaria que carregasse somente 1 vez por acesso, exemplo se continuar navegando não mais irá carregar, porem se voltar a acessar irá mostrar o preload novamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode setar uma variável no `$_SESSION` e checar se ela foi setada na hora de mostrar o preload, no caso do PHP seria algo assim:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['preload'])) {
   $_SESSION['preload'] = true;
  //código para mostrar o preload
}
?>
```

Com JS você pode fazer usando cookie por exemplo:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, days) {
    var d = new Date();
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    }else {        
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkPreload() {
    var preload = getCookie("preload");
    if (preload == "") {
        console.log("mostrar preload");
        setCookie("preload", 1, 1);
    } else {
        console.log("já mostrou o preload");
    }
}

checkPreload();
```

Comment: Eu não entendo muito de PHP, como eu montaria o código PHP no meu html, uma vez que utilizo uma div, outra coisa com cookie o mais ideal seria salvar o cookie até a permanência do browser.

Comment: Certo, você poderia estão no evento `onunload` apagar o cookie

Comment: eu não consegui mesmo montar, você poderia me dar um exemplo de como seria o código?

Comment: Você pode setar o cookie sem a data de expiração, nesse caso ele será removido ao final da sessão do browser, quando for fechado. Alterei a função para permitir fazer isso, aí você usa `setCookie('preload', 1)`

Comment: Fernando sem querer abusar vc pode me passar um contato para que eu possa resolver esta questão?

Comment: @Renato qual o seu e-mail?

Comment: renssis@hotmail.com @fernandoandrade